# can a foreign key column be linked to multiple entities in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to link a foreign kry to multiple 3 entities, so the foreign key column can take one of these 3 entities primary key as a value, is it possible?

in this code i tried to assigne these 3 foreign key to the column operation

```
public class workflow {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_operation", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private demande_de_conge demande_de_conge;
    
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_operation", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private annulation annulation;
    
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_operation", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private regularisation regularisation;
}
```

```
public class demande_de_conge {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id_demande;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="demande_de_conge", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<workflow>workflow;

}
```

```
public class regularisation {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id_regularisation;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="regularisation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<workflow>workflow;

}
```

```
public class annulation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id_annulation;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="annulation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<workflow>workflow; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can try this:

```
    @JoinColumn(name = "demande_de_conge", referencedColumnName = "ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_NAME"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown or explained how you want to set the id_operation fk value. But in short, no, you cannot have 3 writable mappings and just force JPA to figure out which reference to use to set the id_operation fk value.

What you can do is set it yourself. You can certainly have 3 OneToOne mappings that use that foreign key, mapped as you did, but you'll need a separate basic mapping so your application (or the entity itself) can decide  on what value belongs in the id_operation fk column. Ie:

```
public class Workflow {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_operation", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Demande_de_conge demande_de_conge;
    
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_operation", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Annulation annulation;
    
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_operation", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Regularisation regularisation;

    @JsonIgnore //? you might want to serialize this value
    @Column(name="id_operation")
    private Long idOperation;
}
```

Your application then can decide when to set the idOperation long value, and maintain it through the set accessor calls on the other 3 reference mappings. Alternatively, you can use a PrePersist/PreUpdate to check the 3 references and verify that if one or more are set, the idOperation reflects the expected value. ie:

```
@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
validateAndSetIdOperation() {
  Long tempId = null;
  if (null != annulation) {
    tempId =  annulation.getId();
    if (null != demande_de_conge && tempId != demande_de_conge.getId()) {
      throw Exception("conflicting references set");
    }
    if (null != regularisation && tempId != regularisation.getId()) {
      throw Exception("conflicting references set");
    }
  } else if (null != demande_de_conge) {
    tempId =  annulation.getId();
    if (null != regularisation && tempId != regularisation.getId()) {
      throw Exception("conflicting references set");
    }
  } else if (null != regularisation.getId) {
    tempId = regularisation.getId();
  }
 idOperation = tempId;
}
```

Note though that Workflow instance will only be able to be created and assigned the idOperation value after the referenced entities have their IDs assigned. Since JPA isn't pulling the ID from the references, you'll have to make sure your code that does and puts it into the idOperation property is executed after it is assigned. This might mean you need to make save (persist/merge) calls on the reference entities and even flush the transaction to have IDs assigned first, before saving workflows.

Also note, these 3 references are not independent. Any value placed in the id_operation foreign key column will force JPA to use to check if records existing in all 3 of the referenced tables. That means if you are using independent sequences for those values, you may try creating a workflow, giving it a regularisation that has an id of say 101, and later on finding that the same workflow now has references to demande_de_conge and annulation because they exist with ids of 101. If this isn't what you want, you'll need extra data in your workflow to tell things which of the 3 the id_operation actually refers to. This is complicated, so you might be better of doing this yourself - just have the type string and idOperation basic mappings and then query for the Demande_de_conge, Annulation or Regularisation when required yourself instead of making JPA providers do it.